# does MarkdownSharp include client/javascript bits?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, markdown, markdownsharp

Im trying to add a Markdown editor to my site.

I've installed MarkdownSharp via nuget.
Problem is I cant find any documentation on how to use it.

What exactly is this library for?

If it doesnt include the client side editor where can I get one that comes with the toolbar that helps with the markdown syntax?..

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) is just a .NET parser of the [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) language. If you want an editor with toolbars and buttons you could use a WYSIWYG editor. For example Stack Overflow uses a custom modified version of the wmd-editor called [PageDown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown).